# how to pass Boolean value dynamically instead if declaring statically?

Tags: groovy, filemaker

Here this line "boolean  skipfolders = false" how to provide facility for user passing dynamically 
either true or false.

```
    start(true) // here is it pass value dynamically like user,pass parameters
    def start(boolean skip){

            def store  
            boolean  skipfolders = skip;  
            def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
            ftpClient.connect(server)
            ftpClient.login(user,pass)
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
            FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/")
            FTPFile[] folderfileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/sample")

           if(!skipfolders){}      
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I don't really get what you are up to, but you could add a parameter to start() mehod

Comment: In FileMaker tool we are passing input parameters like user,pass values from lest side panel and using in variables console.I tried same for boolean value but it doesn't receive value.Thats why I posted

Comment: You should talk to your coworker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848508/how-to-handles-if-else-in-groovy

Comment: what is `FileMaker` ?

Comment: FileMaker is migration tool which belongs to Apple

Comment: I used like this start(true) 
def start(boolean skip){       
        def store  
        boolean  skipfolders = skip;

Comment: please check my updated question.In start(true) I used true or false is it pass like variable dynamically from user as input

Comment: your updated code should work

Comment: @daggett yes it works fine but i want to pass start(true) as dynamically instead of statically passing true I'm trying to give change to pass input here.How can I achieve it?Do you have any idea please let me know

Comment: What is calling start(true)?  Whatever is making that call can be adjusted as necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handles if-else in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848508/how-to-handles-if-else-in-groovy)